Change colour of text in square brackets
I have data in a google sheet and would like to select all - copy - paste into excel.
For some of the rows, there are text within square brackets where I need it to be in Red.
Example: ‘Insert text here [Highlighted Text]’
I am currently using this macro:
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Text As String
Dim Index1 As Long
Dim Index2 As Long
Text = Target.Text
Index2 = 1
Do
    Index1 = InStr(Index2, Text, "[")
    If Index1 = 0 Then Exit Do
    Index2 = InStr(Index1, Text, "]")
    If Index2 = 0 Then Exit Do
    Target.Characters(Index1, Index2 - Index1 + 1).Font.Color = &HFF
Loop
    End Sub

It works if I move data one row by one row.
However, it’s a few thousand rows of data so I will need to select all, copy all, and paste all.
And when I do this, the macro does not work anymore (error message will pop up).
Im very new to excel macros so if possible please guide me step by step, I will really appreciate it!

When you paste a range, then the Target will be also a range not a single cell.
Therefore need to iterate through the range.
The below mod of your code will do that.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Text As String
Dim Index1 As Long
Dim Index2 As Long

For Each cel In Target
Text = cel.Text
Index2 = 1
    Index1 = InStr(Index2, Text, "[")
    If Index1 <> 0 Then
        Index2 = InStr(Index1, Text, "]")
        If Index2 <> 0 Then
            cel.Characters(Index1, Index2 - Index1 + 1).Font.Color = &HFF
        End If
    End If
Next cel
    End Sub



Thank you! Tried this out and it works.

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    Dim regex As Object, m As Object, cel as Range, r As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
     ' build regex pattern
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
       .Global = True
       .MultiLine = True
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "\[([^]]+)\]" ' [(any text not ])]
    End With
    
    ' color text inside []
    For Each cel In Target.Cells
       For Each m In regex.Execute(cel)
           cel.Characters(m.firstindex + 2, Len(m) - 2).Font.Color = vbRed '&HFF
           'r = r + 1
       Next
    Next
    'MsgBox Target.Cells.Count & " cells scanned" & vbLf & r & " changes in " & _
    '       Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation, Target.Address

End Sub


Thank you for your input!

An alternative using Regular Expressions which works only in Column A
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myStr As String, regExp As Object, j As Integer
    Dim objMatches As Object, xRng As Range, xMatch As Object
    
    If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Set regExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
        
        regExp.Pattern = "\[(.*?)\]"
        regExp.Global = True
        
        For Each xRng In Selection
            j = 0
            Set objMatches = regExp.Execute(xRng.Text)
            For Each xMatch In objMatches
                xRng.Characters(xMatch.FirstIndex + j, xMatch.Length + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
            Next
        Next
    End If
    
    Set objMatches = Nothing
    Set regExp = Nothing
End Sub


Thank you for your input!

You are welcome, you can consider upvoting my answer as it seems working for you
